# how to make a curve that never goes down in y over time?

Tags: integration

(for motion graphics) I need to take an audio clip's curve, and give it a rule: if you ever go down in the y axis, I need you to plateau instead. Attached is a sin curve that has that rule implemented, and here is an equation I found that does what I'm looking for(X = (time-sin(time)*cos(time))/2), only I can't make it work with my audio clip (it still goes down instead of plateauing)
[Sinesquaredwithantiderivative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05sqm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

"[G]o down in the y axis" means "derivative less than zero". So you want to replace all of the parts with negative derivative with flat sections instead. Let $f(x)$ be your original function. You want to define a new derivative

$$
g'(x) = \max\{0, f'(x)\} .
$$

The $\max$ turns all of the negative values into zero. This is the derivative of the function you want, so

$$
g(x) = \int_0^x g'(t) dt = \int_0^x \max\{0, f'(t)\} dt
$$

is your function. I don't think you can simplify that in general.

Comment: cheers, will try to implement this in maya. thanks for the help!

Comment: @AndrewMohr You can click the check mark next to my answer to accept it.